# Trying to Convert the following query into Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have been trying to Convert the following query into Linq, I tried with Linq pad etc, its throwing me errors, still will try in this meantime posting this, if somebody has good understanding about it. I am using C# for my programming, any help would great. thank you

```
declare @id int
select a.BranchId, a.Name BranchName, b.ViolationTypeId, c.ViolationTypeName, d.ViolationId, SUM(d.PenaltyAssessed) PenaltyAssessed 
from Branches a
inner join BranchViolationTypes b on a.BranchId=b.BranchId
inner join ViolationTypes c on b.ViolationTypeId=c.ViolationTypeId
inner join Violations d on d.ViolationTypeId=c.ViolationTypeId
where a.Active=1 and d.ViolationIsActive=1 and d.CaseId=@Id
group by a.BranchId, a.Name, b.ViolationTypeId, c.ViolationTypeName, d.ViolationId
```

@id is parameter that comes, remaining all we have to group to

[image]

Comment: Can you post what you have tried, and the error you get?

Comment: I can't add an image in the comment but added it to the question above my friend

Comment: Post your model.

Comment: From your screenshot, why are you typing SQL syntax when your selected language is c#?

Comment: I did select sql now still didn't get the linq

Comment: I did add connection too, but still its now giving me the Linq, any help please?

Comment: LINQ Pad do not convert SQL to LINQ Query. You have to do that by the hands.

Comment: I thought it would sorry my friend :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to write the query as Linq, like this:

```cs
from a in Branches
join b in BranchViolationTypes on a.BranchId equals b.BranchId
join c in ViolationTypes on b.ViolationTypeId equals c.ViolationTypeId
join d in Violations on d.ViolationTypeId equals c.ViolationTypeId
where a.Active == 1 && d.ViolationIsActive == 1 && d.CaseId == 1
group d by new { a.BranchId, a.Name, b.ViolationTypeId, c.ViolationTypeName, d.ViolationId } into g
select new 
{
    BranchId = g.Key.BranchId, 
    BranchName = g.Key.Name, 
    ViolationTypeId = g.Key.ViolationTypeId, 
    ViolationTypeName = g.Key.ViolationTypeName, 
    ViolationId = g.Key.ViolationId, 
    PenaltyAssessed = g.Sum(o => o.PenaltyAssessed),
}
```

Comment: Hi its awesome thank you, but if I want to count and then calculate penaltyasessed/count, can you please help me thanks a lot please

Comment: g.Sum(o => o.PenaltyAssessed) / g.Count()